# REACT: Stale state in functions but not markup

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

I have a useEffect like this in my React Component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const result = await getCountries();
      const segmentRes = await getSegments();
      setCountries(result);
      setSegments(segmentRes);
      setShowSegments(segmentRes.length > 0);
      setDisableTeacherSignup(!(await doesTeacherCodeExist(teacherCode)));
    }
    init();
  }, [teacherCode]);
```

`teacherCode` is set like this when the page first renders: `const teacherCode = paramQuery.get('code');`

`setSegments` updates the state variable `segments`. The function is being executed correctly and the updated `segments` variable is reflected in the markup here (this is how I know the state is being updated when I would like it to):

```
<select id="teachingSpace" ref={segmentSelect} name="segmentId" onChange={toggleSchoolBoardVisibility} required>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose...</option>
       { segments.map((x) => (
          <option value={x.segmentId}>{x.name}</option>
      )) }
</select>
```

However in the functions that use this segments variable and are called after the useEffect, segments is still the default value (unpopulated). The following is an example of a function that should use the updated `segments` variable, but uses the default instead.

```
const toggleSchoolBoardVisibility = () => {
    console.log(segments)
    if (segmentSelect.current.value === 'DEV') { // To Do: Remove hardcoded val
      setShowSchoolBoardInput(false);
    } else {
      setShowSchoolBoardInput(true);
    }
  };
```

EDIT:
This is how the variables being used are defined:

```
export default function SignupTeacher() {
  const teacherCode = paramQuery.get('code');
  const [segments, setSegments] = useState([]);
....
```

EDIT:
The file contains around 30 state variables. Could that be a reason that stale vars are being used?

Comment: can you provide all code of component to see the problem ?

Comment: Which sections would provide clarification? The code is very long

Comment: where you put `toggleSchoolBoardVisibility `. Dou you have link to Github or something?

Comment: toggleSchoolBoardVisibility is in the component. I know it's being called because the console.log() statement works.

Comment: Do you know why the state variable would be accurate in the markup but not in the onChange callback (toggleSchoolBoardVisibility)

Comment: if I don't see code I can not tell you

Comment: how do you call the `toggleSchoolBoardVisibility` function?

Comment: It's in the onChange method of the select element